# Geolocation, latitude and longitude not defined after first call

Tags: javascript, button, geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

I have a button that calls a function called HomeTest(). Within that function I call geoFindMe(), a simple geolocation function. This geoFindMe() gives me a var latitude and var longitude. Within the HomeTest() I use these variables to see whether I am in a certain polygon. 
If I am in the right polygon, the button should change to another .html-file

My **problem** is, that I have to press the button TWICE to make the site load on the new .html-file, as it doesn't seem to get the latitude & longitude variables with the first try, even though I'm calling the geoFindMe() before using the variables. I'm a little new to js so I'm not quite sure why I don't get relocated to the new .html-file after one click when I am in the correct area.
Somebody got any idea?

```
function geoFindMe() {
  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Your browser doesn't support geolocation.</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  };

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "The site was not able to locate you";
    alert("Please use another browser.");
  };


  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}


function HomeTest(){
    geoFindMe();
    var polygon = [ [ longitude1, latitude1], [ longitude2, latitude2], [ longitude3, latitude3], [ longitude4, latitude4] ];
    insideTest([ longitude, latitude ], polygon); // true -> point coordinates that are searched
   //alert("is inside is " + isInsideTest + " " + latitude + " " + longitude);
    //Test_LockButton();
    if(isInsideTest){
        location.href = './html/testhome.html';
    }
}
```

This is the function that checks, wether the latitude&longitude are within the 4 points of the polygon (see above)

```
function insideTest(point, vs) {

    var x = point[0], y = point[1];

    for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = vs[i][0], yi = vs[i][1];
        var xj = vs[j][0], yj = vs[j][1];

        var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y))
            && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
        if (intersect) isInsideTest = !isInsideTest;
    }

    return isInsideTest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple enough issue that's causing you this grief, the getCurrentPosition function is asynchronous, meaning that you don't have the result by the time you call insideTest. When you click the second time, the variables have been stored and everything works as expected. If you put a delay of a few hundred milliseconds before calling insideTest everything would be OK, however this is not very good practice, it's better to define a callback function to call when the position is available, here's an example:

```
function insideTest(point, vs) {

    var isInsideTest = false;
    var x = point[0], y = point[1];

    for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = vs[i][0], yi = vs[i][1];
        var xj = vs[j][0], yj = vs[j][1];

        var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y))
            && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
        if (intersect) isInsideTest = !isInsideTest;
    }

    return isInsideTest;
}

function geoFindMe(successCallback) {
    if (!navigator.geolocation){
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Your browser doesn't support geolocation.</p>";
        return;
    }

    function success(position) {
        latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        successCallback();
    };

    function error() {
        output.innerHTML = "The site was not able to locate you";
        alert("Please use another browser.");
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}

function homeTestCallback() {
    var polygon = [ [ longitude1, latitude1], [ longitude2, latitude2], [ longitude3, latitude3], [ longitude4, latitude4] ];
    var isInsidePolygon = insideTest([ longitude, latitude ], polygon);
    if(isInsidePolygon) {
        location.href = './html/testhome.html';
    }
}

function HomeTest() {
    // Pass in a function to call when the position is ready
    geoFindMe(homeTestCallback);
}
```